# react/redux is registering 2 calls to a reducer even though the action only fires once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I can't figure out what's causing this behavior. I have an action that's only being fired once, the reducer of that type gets the appropriate payload, but then immediately receives another call, without the action having been fired, and causes an error to be thrown.

In my files I have the following setup:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({fetchTile, fetchSinglePlan, clearTile, clearPlans, clearPlan}, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps({user, tile, plans}){
    return {
        user,
        tile:tile.tile,
        plans:plans.plans,
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SingleTileDisplay));
```

I realize tile.tile isn't a great naming system, but that's not what's concerning me at the moment.

the action is called on this line:

```
componentDidMount(){
        let tileId = this.props.match.params.tileId;
        this.props.fetchTile(tileId)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res);
            });
    }
```

The following action then fires:

```
export const FETCH_TILE = 'FETCH_TILE';
export function fetchTile(tileId){
    let url = `/tiles/single/${tileId}`;
    let tileRequest = axios.get(url);
    return ({
        type: FETCH_TILE,
        payload:tileRequest
    });
}
```

and this is the reducer that handles everything:

```
import {FETCH_TILE} from "../actions/action_tile";
import {CLEAR_TILE} from "../actions/action_tile";

export default function(state={tile:null}, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_TILE:
            return {tile:action.payload.data.tile};

        case CLEAR_TILE:
            return Object.assign({}, action.payload);
    }
    return state;
}
```

When the component mounts everything behaves as expected, the action fires, the reducer receives the correct data. I put break points before the action and the reducer to see when they were firing. However, right after the reducer receives its data:
[image]

the reducer is called again and this error results

[image]

Comment: `axios.get(url)` returns a promise, so trying to access `action.payload.data.tile` directly in your reducer will not work as expected.

Comment: I'm using redux-promise middleware

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have any `options.filter` code anywhere else in your code, or might that be an axios error?

Comment: unfortunately the stack trace points to a line in bundle.js which is a compiled file and unreadable to me.

Comment: Do you have the option of changing the webpack config? You could add some [source maps](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) to help you.

Comment: that's a place for me to start. I'm not sure how to do that, but I'll look it up

Comment: state.tile nulled on second pass? no errors, redirects, strange behaviour/duplicated requests in network tab?